# Why getting an error: 'should not push route with duplicated key' with NavigationStateUtils in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

In my React Native + Redux, I have the following reducer set up for navigation using NavigationStateUtils:

```
import { PUSH_ROUTE, POP_ROUTE } from '../Constants/ActionTypes'
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'

import Login from '../Components/Login'

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental

const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

And got a button component that calls on the navigation actions like so:

```
  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

  render(){
    const route = {
      type: 'push',
      route: {
        key: this.props.navKey,
        title: this.props.pageName,
        component: this.props.componentName
      }
    }

    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handleNavigate(route)}>
        <Text style={styles}>{pr.pageName}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
```

The first time I press the button, it navigates properly and there is no error. But when I press the button again, I get the following error: `should not push route with duplicated key`.

How could I resolve the issue with what I implemented in the reducer using the `NavigationStateUtils`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your reducer for push. What you need to do is-

1. Check if the key route which you have to push does it already exist in stack.
2. If it doesn't then push that route in the stack
3. If it is already present then find its index and make a clone of existing state which doesn't contain that duplicate route.
4. Now all you have to do is update your state with cloned state.

   ```
    case PUSH_ROUTE:{

         // trying to push the route where we already are, no need to change a thing
             if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) 
                return state;
         // ensure no duplicate keys
             const index = state.routes.findIndex((route) => {
             return action.route.key === route.key && action.route.title ===route.title;
            });
             if (index > -1) {
                      const clonedState = Object.assign({}, state);
                      clonedState.routes.splice(index, 1);
                      return NavigationStateUtils.push(clonedState, action.route);
                      }
          // normal case for a push
                return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route);
   ```

   }